# Delay between on screen display and parallel port trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a research project which needs precise timing/synchronize between the on screen display and a trigger from parallel port in Unity.

What I am trying to do is to flash the screen to white while sending a trigger to the parellel port at the same time (desired difference is within 10ms).

I mesured the screen flash with a photodiode to determine the exact time it turns white, and synchronize it with the trigger from parellel port. I always observed a delay of 40 - 70ms between the trigger and the flash (the flash arrived slower) which is my main problem.

What I have tried so far:
- Update the flash and send the trigger in the same frame (bigger delay)
- Update the flash -> WaitForEndOfFrame() -> send trigger (lower delay but still big). Below is a sample code:

```
IEnumerator UpdateParallelPort()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        if (flashed == FlashState.ToWhite)
        {
            parallelPort.SendTrigger();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tested if the flash take multiple frames to be rendered by using ReadPixels to determine at what frame the screen turn white, but it was not the case, it was in the same frame when I issued the command. So I guess the delay comes from the time the buffer being sent to screen ? If that is the case, is there anyway to determine/synchronize the exact timing, or to minimize it ?

This is my first post in Stackoverflow, hope that I explained it clear enough. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which needs precise timing

I have bad news, completely forget it.

Unity is a game engine through-and-through.

The whole entire raison d'etre, the most fundamental aspects of it, is that it lets you render mesh of dinosaurs etc, with "total compromise" of *granular time*, and reasonable overall perceptive time.

Unfortunately, you literally could not choose a worse milieu for the project!  Sorry!  :O

Comment: Yeah after multiple tries I figure that might be the case. Too bad I am forced to use Unity for this project, I should look for a workaround now. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: looking forward to your next question, @ldkv hope we can help more!